# How to sort list of strings

Tags: python

I have an initial list of strings:

```
List1 = ["2,6,4,5", "3,7,4,2"]
```

I would like each string to be sorted in ascending order:

```
Output = ["2,4,5,6", "2,3,4,7"]
```

May I know how do I do that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. What do you imagine are the logical steps to solve the problem? What don't you know how to do? What happens when you try to write the code? How do you know that this output is correct? What is the rule that tells you what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can try splitting, sort, then join

```py
List1 = ["2,6,4,5", "3,7,4,2"]
sortedList = []

for s in List1:
    nums = s.split(",")
    nums.sort()
    sortedList.append(",".join(nums))
```

Thanks for pointing out that the above doesn't work for numbers > 10 and negative numbers, I forgot that it was sorting with strings. Although the question didn't really specify, it makes sense that sorting should be based on number rather than string so update:

```py
for s in List1:
    nums = s.split(",")
    nums = list(map(int, nums))
    nums.sort()
    nums = list(map(str, nums))
    sortedList.append(",".join(nums))
```

Comment: With `List1 = ["20,6,400,5", "3,7,4,2"]`, the output is `['20,400,5,6', '2,3,4,7']`, which is totally wrong. How could this answer get 2 upvotes btw??

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: the requirements were obviously deficient since they gave test data indicating all numbers were positive and less than ten :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in order to evaluating the strings as Python values:

```
import ast
List1 = ["2,6,4,5", "3,7,4,2"]
print([",".join(map(str, sorted(ast.literal_eval(item)))) for item in List1])
```

Out:

```
['2,4,5,6', '2,3,4,7']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using list comprehension

```
List1 = ["2,6,4,5", "3,7,4,2"]
Output = [','.join(sorted(lis)) for lis in [s.split(',') for s in List1]]

['2,4,5,6', '2,3,4,7']
```